# Tensoflow ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified

Tags: tensorflow

I do generally use Tensorflow Keras backend but recently I'm working on a project where there is need of T.F 1.x

I'm trying a simple code, but getting an error:

```
x2 = tf.constant(-2.0, name="x", dtype=tf.float32)
a = tf.placeholder(name='a',dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.constant(13.0, name="b", dtype=tf.float32)

y = tf.Variable(tf.add(tf.multiply(a, x2), b))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    print(session.run(init,feed_dict={a:5.0}))
```

ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified at y=Variable()... line.

Does anyone know the solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The variable "y" is dependent on the variable "a" which is a placeholder. So defining the shape of "a" will make code run properly

```
x2 = tf.constant(-2.0, name="x", dtype=tf.float32)
a = tf.placeholder(name='A',shape=(1,),dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.constant(13.0, name="b", dtype=tf.float32)

y = tf.Variable(tf.add(tf.multiply(a, x2), b))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    print(session.run(init,feed_dict={a:[5.0]}))
    print(session.run(y))
```